# How to fix unexpected EOF while parsing in python 3.6?

Tags: python-3.x, eof

Im getting the EOF at the end of the program when i try to run it. i dont really know how to fix it. at first i was getting "if" as an invalid syntax but i think i was able to fix that. thanks for the help

while True:

```
try: 

    print("Do you want to enter a number?")  
    print("y - yes")  
    print("n - no")  
    choice = int(input("Enter here: "))  
    if choice == y:  
        print("")  
        count = number

    for indice in range(1,number + 1, 1):  
        print(number + indice)  
        print("")  
        print("All done")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a `except` to match `try`.

Note that there are other issues with your code that will break it, even once you've added `except`.  For example,

```
if choice == y: 
...
```

This should be `'y'` instead of `y`.  As it is, `y` is expected to be a variable, but you're looking to match on the user input `'y'` or `'n'`.

Also, if you want a string input, then:

```
choice = int(input("Enter here: "))
```

will throw an error if you enter, say, `'y'`:

```
invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'y'
```

Try taking things one line at a time and making sure you understand what's supposed to happen at each point, and test it.  Then put them together.

Comment: You're welcome.  If this answer resolved your issue, please marked it accepted by clicking the check box to the left of the answer.