# SyntaxError while using try:

Tags: python

The following code results in `Syntax Error: Unexpected EOF while parsing`. I cant seem to figure out while it wont run even after deleting almost everything. I've tried removing unnecessary code and deleted functions that are in the way my some chance.

```
def create_entry():
    ...

try:        
    while True: #Puts Everything In A Loop
            option_1 = int(input("What Would You Like To Do To The Cpu Database, 1) Make An Entry, 2) Read The Data Or 3) Delete Data. Type 1, 2, ,3 "))
            if option_1 == "1":
                    create_entry()
            else: 
                print("Please Type A Valid Reply")
```

I expect it to run but no matter what I try, the same error is shown.

Comment: "`EOF`" stands for "end of file." The interpreter encountered the end of the file before it expected to reach the end of the file. It's like finding a period in the middle of a sentence, before the sentence is finished.

Comment: try adding a blank line at the end and making `except Exception as e: pass` blocks for your `try` blocks

Comment: BTW, `sql_query` is a `str` value not `tuple`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix unexpected EOF while parsing in python 3.6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46741791/how-to-fix-unexpected-eof-while-parsing-in-python-3-6)

Comment: Your query string is also missing a table name, INSERT queries do not return a result to iterate over and you don't seem to be committing your insert.

Answer (score 3):

a `try` caluse must ***always*** be followed by at least one `except` clause.

```
# ILLEGAL CODE
try:
    print("hello world")
```

The following is an example of correct code:

```
# OKAY CODE
try:
    print("hello world")
except ValueError as exc:
    pass
```

The reason you got an error is that the end of the file was reached ***before*** the try-catch block was finished.

```
try:        
    while True: #Puts Everything In A Loop
            option_1 = int(input("What Would You Like To Do To The Cpu Database, 1) Make An Entry, 2) Read The Data Or 3) Delete Data. Type 1, 2, ,3 "))
            if option_1 == "1":
                    create_entry()
            else: 
                print("Please Type A Valid Reply")
# MISSING `EXCEPT`!!!!!!
```

You would get the same error if you left any other half-finished statement at the end of the file. For example if you wrote `x =` without a right-hand-side, then the interpreter would encounter the end-of-the-file (EOF) unexpectedly. It would encounter EOF ***before*** the right-hand-side of the assignment statement was filled in.