# How to fetch data from SQL query in Python

Tags: python, data-science

Good Afternoon,
I wrote a query in MySQL, and I want to execute the same query in Python.
The Code I wrote as Follows.
1.

```
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error


try:
connection = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',
                                      database='AdventureWorks2012',
                                      user='root',
                                      password='r@#*****')
```

3. 

```
sql_select_Query = "select * from Person.person"
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute(sql_select_Query)
    records = cursor.fetchall()
```

However, I'm getting following error message while running part two-
''File "", line 5
password='r@#*****')
^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing''

Any suggestion please how to overcome this problem?

Comment: Have you added `except` after your `try` block of code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix unexpected EOF while parsing in python 3.6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46741791/how-to-fix-unexpected-eof-while-parsing-in-python-3-6)

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `except` clause:

```
try:
    connection = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',
                                      database='AdventureWorks2012',
                                      user='root',
                                      password='r@#*****')
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

You should check the [`documentation`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html) for more information.